# Feedback tester python

Tags: python, python-2.7

Hi for a given function I have 2 parameters which are string and an Int but I don't know which comes first. So I have a function "pick_type()" that tries to guess the order of the parameters. So my question is when "pick_type()" incorrectly guesses the order, how do I record this and make sure "pick_type()" never tries that specific order again ?

```
 for iteration in range(0, 10):

    args = []
    print("\n  def test%d(self):" % (iteration))
    for input in range(num_arguments):

        args += pick_type()

    try:
        result = target(*args)
        code = test_to_string(target, args, result)


    except TypeError as error:
        code = test_to_string_exc(target, args, error) 


    for line in code.splitlines():
        print("    "+line)

 def pick_type():
    lista = []

    words = ['rhythms', 'rhythms', 'manager', 'training', 'hotel', 'destroy']
    word = choice(words)
    num = random.randint(-100, 100)

    lists = [word,num]

    choices = choice(lists)


    if choices == word:
        lista.append(word)
    else:
        lista.append(num)


    return lista
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest wrapping your method in a class, then you can have a persistent list of bad orders.  It's not clear to me what you mean by an "order", but whatever it is, hopefully this pseudo-code helps:

```
class PickType:
   def __init__(self):
       self._bad_orders = []

   def pick_type(self):
       ...# insert body here
       if order in self._bad_orders:
           ## pick another order
       ## test the new order
       if <order is bad>:
          self._bad_orders.append(order)

   ## if your test for bad orders is performed outside pick_type(), you just need a method to add to the list of bad_orders
   def add_bad_order(self, order):
       self._bad_orders.append(order)
```

Comment: what I mean by order is if the function takes in a string first then an int, an incorrect order would be "pick type" guessing int as the first parameter and then string as the second.

Comment: so in that case, you can add the tuple `(int, str)` to your `_bad_orders` list